# Missing :id in my routes in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

### hi,

I am having a problem with my routes. Just noticed a strange thing. I have no :id in my show/edit/... routes.

This is my rake.routes output:

```
    WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.2
                      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
          new_person_session GET    /persons/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#new
              person_session POST   /persons/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#create
      destroy_person_session DELETE /persons/sign_out(.:format)           devise/sessions#destroy
             person_password POST   /persons/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#create
         new_person_password GET    /persons/password/new(.:format)       devise/passwords#new
        edit_person_password GET    /persons/password/edit(.:format)      devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /persons/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /persons/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#update
           supplier_password POST   /suppliers/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
       new_supplier_password GET    /suppliers/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
      edit_supplier_password GET    /suppliers/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /suppliers/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /suppliers/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
        facilitator_password POST   /facilitators/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
    new_facilitator_password GET    /facilitators/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
   edit_facilitator_password GET    /facilitators/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /facilitators/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /facilitators/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
           customer_password POST   /customers/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
       new_customer_password GET    /customers/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
      edit_customer_password GET    /customers/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /customers/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /customers/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
cancel_customer_registration GET    /customers/cancel(.:format)           devise/registrations#cancel
       customer_registration POST   /customers(.:format)                  devise/registrations#create
   new_customer_registration GET    /customers/sign_up(.:format)          devise/registrations#new
  edit_customer_registration GET    /customers/edit(.:format)             devise/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /customers(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update
                             PUT    /customers(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /customers(.:format)                  devise/registrations#destroy
                  home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                 home#index
                        root GET    /                                     home#index
             suppliers_index GET    /suppliers/index(.:format)            suppliers#index
          facilitators_index GET    /facilitators/index(.:format)         facilitators#index
             customers_index GET    /customers/index(.:format)            customers#index
               new_customers GET    /customers/new(.:format)              customers#new
       customers_newCustomer POST   /customers/newCustomer(.:format)      customers#newCustomer
      customers_editCustomer GET    /customers/editCustomer(.:format)     customers#editCustomer
                     parties POST   /parties(.:format)                    parties#create
                 new_parties GET    /parties/new(.:format)                parties#new
                edit_parties GET    /parties/edit(.:format)               parties#edit
                             GET    /parties(.:format)                    parties#show
                             PATCH  /parties(.:format)                    parties#update
                             PUT    /parties(.:format)                    parties#update
                             DELETE /parties(.:format)                    parties#destroy
               parties_index GET    /parties/index(.:format)              parties#index
                visitors_new POST   /visitors/new(.:format)               visitors#new
             visitors_create POST   /visitors/create(.:format)            visitors#create
```

this is my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 # devise_for :people
  devise_for :persons, :skip => :registrations
  devise_for :suppliers, :facilitators, skip: [:registrations, :sessions]
  devise_for :customers, :skip => :sessions

  # routes for all users
  authenticated :persons do
  end

  # routes only for customers
  authenticated :customers, lambda {|u| u.type == "Customer"} do
  end

  # routes only for companies
  authenticated :facilitators, lambda {|u| u.type == "Facilitator"} do
  end

  # routes only for suppliers
  authenticated :suppliers, lambda {|u| u.type == "Supplier"} do
  end

  # mde toevoegeingen
  get 'home/index'
  root to: "home#index"

  get 'suppliers/index'
  get 'facilitators/index'
  get 'customers/index'

  resource :customers, :only => :new
  match 'customers/newCustomer', to: 'customers#newCustomer', via: :post
  match 'customers/editCustomer', to: 'customers#editCustomer', via: :get

  resource :parties
  get 'parties/index'

  match 'visitors/new', to: 'visitors#new', via: :post
  match 'visitors/create', to: 'visitors#create', via: :post

end
```

My urls show a '.' instead of a '/' before the 'id'.  this is an example url for the `show` method of a model:

`http://localhost:3000/parties.2`

The strange thing is that the normal routing is working. Strange because the dot is intended for defining the format.

Now I need the format becase of a `remote: true` behaviour I am implementing I am getting into troubles.

What did I do wrong?

regards Martijn

Comment: How does your `link_to` to looks like?

Comment: You probably want "resources" instead of "resource", in your routes...

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
resource :parties
```

To:

```
resources :parties
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like Brad Werth said in comments.

the plural `resources`

```
resources :photos
```

creates

```
GET /photos Photos  index   display a list of all photos
GET /photos/new Photos  new return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST    /photos Photos  create  create a new photo
GET /photos/1   Photos  show    display a specific photo
GET /photos/1/edit  Photos  edit    return an HTML form for editing a photo
PUT /photos/1   Photos  update  update a specific photo
DELETE  /photos/1   Photos  destroy delete a specific photo
```

in contrast to `Singular Resources`

> You can also apply RESTful routing to singleton resources within your
>   application. In this case, you use map.resource instead of
>   map.resources and the route generation is slightly different. For
>   example, a routing entry of

```
resource :geocoded

GET /geocoder/new   Geocoders   new return an HTML form for creating the new geocoder
POST    /geocoder   Geocoders   create  create the new geocoder
GET /geocoder   Geocoders   show    display the one and only geocoder resource
GET /geocoder/edit  Geocoders   edit    return an HTML form for editing the geocoder
PUT /geocoder   Geocoders   update  update the one and only geocoder resource
DELETE  /geocoder   Geocoders   destroy delete the geocode resource
```